# account deletion - how long does it usually take?

Tags: support, deletion, user-accounts

I am wondering usually how long does an account deletion usually take here?  I have followed the steps and are just after the time frame.

Thank you.

Comment: Been thinking about this for a while, weighing up the pros and cons as this site has some very interesting content.  However, many of my answers are ignored and what I felt was a rude response I got to my latest (now deleted) question, made the decision easier for me.  Biology is an area outside of my expertise, so I was learning it - but I think I will stick with documentaries.

Comment: sad to see you go.  I liked this question in particular: http://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/9049/what-biological-constraints-are-there-on-how-large-a-spider-can-grow but admittedly didn't up vote it at the time (when I suppose it would have mattered).

Comment: @AtlLED that's okay, I have had the general impression that my contributions here are not really that acceptable (particularly my answers) - after the rude response on my deleted question, it is pretty much confirmed.  I am an enthusiast, not a professional biologist after all.

Comment: this is the post in question http://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/10161/how-do-kidney-stones-form - it is deleted, but still visible to those that can see deleted posts.

Comment: Too bad that you want to leave. The site needs more users, both professionals and enthusiasts. I cannot speak about your personal reasons for leaving, but lots of your content has been upvoted (therefore seen as valuable) and you have gained relatively high rep an a fairly short amount of time. I cannot view the deleted Q, so no comments on that. However, as always on the internet, you sometimes need to be thick-skinned.

Comment: Biology is out of my area of expertise (Physics is my area), the content will still be here -so there is no harm there. It is not about being 'thick skinned', it's about what can I do for the site - I do not feel that my contributions are of suitable worth and the rude comments in the deleted question just simply tipped the balance - convincing me that my concern was valid.  Looking at my contributions, I agree with the message behind the rude comments and decided to stop contributing, as I am not a biology expert thus my posts aren't likely to improve to what some members want for the site.

Comment: @UV-D Fair enough. I still think that your contributions have been valuable though, both by raising topics and in answers. Everybody has highs and lows in the quality of their posts.

Comment: I'd like to add my vote to those who think you should stay. Looking through your profile, 20 out of 21 (non-deleted) questions have been upvoted at least once, and all but 4 have at least 1 answer. All but 3 of your 29 answers have been upvoted, and 6 were accepted as correct (including 1 that wasn't upvoted, but the poster didn't have enough rep). Bio.SE is a very diverse place, with lots of different types of questions, and lots of different types of users. All that's required is a willingness to learn, the desire to share what appropriate knowledge you have, and the ability ...

Comment: ... to do some basic research before asking a question. Please, don't worry about your deleted question too much, I've asked not-so-intelligent things before myself :) We are really striving to make this place welcoming, and while I didn't see the rude comments to your deleted question, I'm very sorry to hear that they were the straw that broke the camel's back. Please consider at least just taking a hiatus from the site, either completely or just from contributing, and see how you feel in time. We'd really like to see you stay, but at the same time I can understand your wanting to leave.

Answer (score 2):

Account deletion is a manual process, you might have to wait until the weekend is over and an SE employee sees the request.

Comment: no problem, thank you for your reply.